# SCP to EC2 not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

So I have a pem file:

```
./test.pem
```

I have a file I want to move to my instance:

```
path/to/my/file.csv
```

and I want to move it to my ec2 instance:

```
ec2-user@11.111.111.11
```

I try to scp the file to my ec2 home directory using:

```
scp -i test.pem path/to/my/file.csv ec2-user@11.111.111.11:~
```

but it prompts me for a password for some reason.  Any idea what I have wrong here?

Output from `-v`:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 11.111.111.11, user ec2-user, command scp -v -d -t ~
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 11.111.111.11 [11.111.111.11] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 11.111.111.11:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx 
debug1: Host '11.111.111.11' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_edxxxxx
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `scp` with `-v` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not offering the `.pem` file you are telling it to. Is that `.pem` locked down with permissions of `600`?

Another thing that might be happening: one or both of the client or server is refusing to try more than a set number of public keys, so add `-F /dev/null` to your scp command, so that your client does not send any of the extra keys (`id_dsa`, `id_ecdsa`, etc).

Comment: I tried the pem at both 400 and 600 with no luck.  What ssh command?  I tried to use `-F /dev/nulll` in my scp but it still looked for the id_rsa files.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "scp" not "ssh", I just confused the two since they have such similar arguments. You did add your public key to the the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote server, right...?

Comment: Hmmm another way to stop sending so many private keys is to use `ssh-add -d /path/to/public-key.pub` (or, to remove ALL keys the agent knows about, `ssh-add -D`).

Comment: my pem key is included in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  With `ssh-add` should I add the pem key or the id_ files?

Comment: The `.pem` file *is* your private key, and that is the file you should add to the agent: `ssh-add ./test.pem`. The public part of this private key is what should be one of the lines in your remote '~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (the line starts with `ssh-rsa AAAA......`).

Comment: So after running ssh-add, it seems to accept the `.pem` key when I scp and then hits a lost connection but it seems like you solved this problem and I just bumped into another one so I am giving you credit until I figure this out.